# Названия космических кораблей + глагол

Tags: глаголы

*"Только появившись в системе, «Чистилище» взял(о) курс прямо к звезде и завис(ло) на максимально близком к ней расстоянии".*

Если у космического корабля название в среднем роде, глаголы при нем ставить тоже в среднем? Или всегда подразумевается слово "корабль"? Извините, может, тупой вопрос, но меня что-то заклинило.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Розенталь, параграф 188:

5. При подлежащем – условном названии применяется принцип грамматического согласования, например: «Известия» увеличили свой тираж; «Воскресение» было впервые опубликовано Л.Н. Толстым в журнале «Нива».(Грамота.ру)

> «Чистилище» взяло курс прямо к звезде и зависло на максимально близком
> к ней расстоянии.

Второй принцип согласования обычно применяется при иноязычных несклоняемых наименованиях промышленных компаний, акционерных обществ, спортивных организаций и т.п., например: «Дженерал моторс корпорейшн» (компания) выплатила акционерам огромные дивиденды; «Тре крунур» (спортивная команда) проиграла нашим хоккеистам оба матча; «Панасоник» (фирма) наладила выпуск видеомагнитофонов новой модели.